# 3dPlot display only a subset of points

Tags: r, graphics, r-plotly, rgl, plot3d

I'm trying to visualize a data set with rgl library: the data set has dimensions 15927 x 6, and contains scores of a pca transformation. I'm afraid I don't know how to show said data set here, (this is my first question, so please excuse me). I've used plot3d to plot the first three vectors, but it shows only a very small subset of points (less than fifty). I've tried changing the  clipping, but it just shows nothing or just one point, whether I increase or decrease the limits. I have this problem just with this particular data set. I've used the same function on another plot in the same script, with no issues. Happens the same with plot_ly. I don't understand what's causing this, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here's my code:

```
new.tw <- as.data.frame(fit.data$objectscores) # new coordinates on the principal components

plot3d(fit.data$objectscores[,4:6], xlab = "Political", ylab = "Civil", zlab = "Partizan") # output only a subset of the original matrix

fig1 <- plot_ly(new.tw, x = ~Racial, y = ~Activism, z = ~Partizan)
fig1 <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig1 <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Political'),
                                   yaxis = list(title = 'Civil'),
                                   zaxis = list(title = 'Partizan')))
fig1 #same problem here
```

this second call however works perfectly. sim.result is another data set, with dimensions 1000 x 6. I've tried also with 100000 observations and still works fine.

```
plot3d(sim.results[,2:4] , col=sim.results[,1], xlab = "Racial", ylab = "Activism", zlab = "Partizan")
```

Thank you in advance, please let me know if i need to provide more information.

EDIT: as requested, here's the first 20 records with

```
dput(head(fit.data$objectscores, 20)))

structure(c(1.50298476621238, 1.50298476621238, 1.50298476621238, 
-1.58568117857448, -0.816526654373636, 0.565715252062814, 1.50298476621238, 
0.938169846654393, -0.264438304359833, -0.89895908781598, -1.58568117857448, 
0.854894719853944, -0.816526654373636, -1.58568117857448, -0.816526654373636, 
-0.264438304359833, 1.50298476621238, 1.50298476621238, -0.816526654373636, 
-0.816526654373636, -0.22195707370619, -0.22195707370619, -0.22195707370619, 
2.92311622515375, -0.9872594008058, 0.155224901527586, -0.22195707370619, 
0.507704817966882, -0.0218926196634168, 3.56657236205749, 2.92311622515375, 
0.57259387796395, -0.9872594008058, 2.92311622515375, -0.9872594008058, 
-0.0218926196634168, -0.22195707370619, -0.22195707370619, -0.9872594008058, 
-0.9872594008058, -0.61967189717146, -0.61967189717146, -0.61967189717146, 
-0.0641863006278279, 0.751877614031531, 0.467590743969311, -0.61967189717146, 
-2.85074009594914, -0.215480514804859, 0.978902546006621, -0.0641863006278279, 
0.7286746842318, 0.751877614031531, -0.0641863006278279, 0.751877614031531, 
-0.215480514804859, -0.61967189717146, -0.61967189717146, 0.751877614031531, 
0.751877614031531, -1.15671269188201, -1.15671269188201, -1.15671269188201, 
-1.02621692332093, -0.192044576245641, -1.63097963620485, -1.15671269188201, 
2.31326205223891, 0.181116196817509, 0.136775914244596, -1.02621692332093, 
1.01664957434761, -0.192044576245641, -1.02621692332093, -0.192044576245641, 
0.181116196817509, -1.15671269188201, -1.15671269188201, -0.192044576245641, 
-0.192044576245641, -0.716947334740032, -0.716947334740032, -0.716947334740032, 
-0.211774508543306, 0.412900956387458, 1.50372485320379, -0.716947334740032, 
3.97207352078232, -0.156636810319296, 0.31991195471995, -0.211774508543306, 
0.237902829961732, 0.412900956387458, -0.211774508543306, 0.412900956387458, 
-0.156636810319296, -0.716947334740032, -0.716947334740032, 0.412900956387458, 
0.412900956387458, 0.777882430991955, 0.777882430991955, 0.777882430991955, 
0.622604024952591, 0.669399975560595, -2.34610692261696, 0.777882430991955, 
1.50641686438724, -1.35856726916514, 1.17683296363845, 0.622604024952591, 
-0.281401001859944, 0.669399975560595, 0.622604024952591, 0.669399975560595, 
-1.35856726916514, 0.777882430991955, 0.777882430991955, 0.669399975560595, 
0.669399975560595), .Dim = c(20L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), c("D1", "D2", "D3", 
"D4", "D5", "D6")))
```

and with

```
head(fit.data$objectscores, 20)
          D1          D2         D3         D4         D5         D6
1   1.5029848 -0.22195707 -0.6196719 -1.1567127 -0.7169473  0.7778824
2   1.5029848 -0.22195707 -0.6196719 -1.1567127 -0.7169473  0.7778824
3   1.5029848 -0.22195707 -0.6196719 -1.1567127 -0.7169473  0.7778824
4  -1.5856812  2.92311623 -0.0641863 -1.0262169 -0.2117745  0.6226040
5  -0.8165267 -0.98725940  0.7518776 -0.1920446  0.4129010  0.6694000
6   0.5657153  0.15522490  0.4675907 -1.6309796  1.5037249 -2.3461069
7   1.5029848 -0.22195707 -0.6196719 -1.1567127 -0.7169473  0.7778824
8   0.9381698  0.50770482 -2.8507401  2.3132621  3.9720735  1.5064169
9  -0.2644383 -0.02189262 -0.2154805  0.1811162 -0.1566368 -1.3585673
10 -0.8989591  3.56657236  0.9789025  0.1367759  0.3199120  1.1768330
11 -1.5856812  2.92311623 -0.0641863 -1.0262169 -0.2117745  0.6226040
12  0.8548947  0.57259388  0.7286747  1.0166496  0.2379028 -0.2814010
13 -0.8165267 -0.98725940  0.7518776 -0.1920446  0.4129010  0.6694000
14 -1.5856812  2.92311623 -0.0641863 -1.0262169 -0.2117745  0.6226040
15 -0.8165267 -0.98725940  0.7518776 -0.1920446  0.4129010  0.6694000
16 -0.2644383 -0.02189262 -0.2154805  0.1811162 -0.1566368 -1.3585673
17  1.5029848 -0.22195707 -0.6196719 -1.1567127 -0.7169473  0.7778824
18  1.5029848 -0.22195707 -0.6196719 -1.1567127 -0.7169473  0.7778824
19 -0.8165267 -0.98725940  0.7518776 -0.1920446  0.4129010  0.6694000
20 -0.8165267 -0.98725940  0.7518776 -0.1920446  0.4129010  0.6694000
```

Here's the result of str():

```
str(fit.data$objectscores)
 num [1:15927, 1:6] 1.503 1.503 1.503 -1.586 -0.817 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:15927] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "D1" "D2" "D3" "D4" ...
```

i didn't mention it (sorry) but i thought the same thing and tried running

```
unique(fit.data$objectscores[,1])
```

for all columns, and obtained 90-100 values as result. Meanwhile, thank you for the reply.

EDIT 2: yes, I added the columns' name later with:

```
colnames(new.tw) <-c("Racial","Activism","Partizan","Political","Civil","Party")
```

I used Gifi library for Non-linear PCA (I started from a matrix of ordinal variables). Here's my (almost) complete code (minus the part where I created the original data set and the next part where I apply some clustering function with mclust library)

```
library(Gifi)
library(rgl)
library(plotly)
data <- read.csv("twitter.data.csv")
data<-data[,-c(1,2)]
#perform ordinal MVAOS (Multivariate Analysis with Optimal Scaling)
fit.data <- princals(data, ndim = 6)
summary(fit.data)
trans <- fit.data$transform #new data after rotation
fit.data$loadings #loadings
new.tw <- as.data.frame(fit.data$objectscores) # new coordinates on the principal components
colnames(new.tw) <-c("Racial","Activism","Partizan","Political","Civil","Party")
plot(fit.data, "screeplot") #screeplot

#plots
plot3d(fit.data$objectscores[,1:3], xlab = "Racial", ylab = "Activism", zlab = "Partizan")
plot3d(fit.data$objectscores[,4:6], xlab = "Political", ylab = "Civil", zlab = "Party")

fig1 <- plot_ly(new.tw, x = ~Racial, y = ~Activism, z = ~Partizan)
fig1 <- fig1 %>% add_markers()
fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title ='Racial'),yaxis = list(title = 'Activism'),zaxis = list(title ='Partizan')))
fig1

fig2 <- plot_ly(new.tw, x = ~Political, y = ~Civil, z = ~Party)
fig2 <- fig2 %>% add_markers()
fig2 <- fig2 %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Political'),yaxis = list(title = 'Civil'),zaxis = list(title ='Party')))
fig2

plot(fit.data, "loadplot", main = "Loadings Plot Twitter Data")
plot(fit.data, "biplot", main = "Biplot Twitter Data")
```

EDIT 3:
I'm adding a picture to clarify: in the last three columns, unique triplets are actually 288 but, as i hope you can see from the image, only 78 or so got plotted.

```
unique(fit.data$objectscores[,4:6])

               D4          D5          D6
1     -1.15671269 -0.71694733  0.77788243
4     -1.02621692 -0.21177451  0.62260402
5     -0.19204458  0.41290096  0.66939998
6     -1.63097964  1.50372485 -2.34610692
8      2.31326205  3.97207352  1.50641686
9      0.18111620 -0.15663681 -1.35856727
10     0.13677591  0.31991195  1.17683296
12     1.01664957  0.23790283 -0.28140100
25    -0.15744958 -0.25383428  1.59358003
33     2.54459730 -2.87594628  0.81783240
40     0.01738647 -0.22521022 -1.09709860
48    -1.36614373 -0.07883616  2.54438101
51     1.31399894  3.50896047  0.69071926
80     0.27039555  3.52239618  2.41042189
96    -2.34122650 -1.31832018 -3.02243232
98    -0.14311675 -0.68745042 -1.31840645
149   -2.20031608 -0.70351162  2.49758506
165    0.19855888 -0.22754270 -1.39564370
184    2.10383101  4.61018470  3.27291544
234   -0.86248719 -0.14320110  0.36113536
240   -0.02695382  0.25133854  1.43830163
287    0.43412528  3.59096959  2.14895323
385   -0.63171653  1.96683790 -1.53040932
430    2.33516626 -2.23783510  2.58433098
465   -1.23564797  0.42633667  2.38910261
567    0.80721853  0.87601401  1.48509758
622   -0.35254779 -0.04933924  0.44809213
665    1.18037930  0.30647624 -0.54286967
671   -0.02831485  0.48147437  0.40793131
698    2.70832703 -2.80737286  0.55636374
830   -2.67458303  1.51716057 -0.62640429
932    1.47772867  3.57753388  0.42925060
957   -0.14311675 -0.68745042 -1.31840645
1148  -1.84041068  2.14183603 -0.57960834
1390   0.18111620 -0.15663681 -1.35856727
1392  -0.06953126  3.65533453  4.33219888
1413   0.18598433 -3.96905623 -1.10750131
1469   1.01664957  0.23790283 -0.28140100
1527  -1.15671269 -0.71694733  0.77788243
1542   0.13989979  3.01722336  2.56570030
1761   1.37049815 -3.36768339  2.69281344
1950   0.09555950  3.49377212  5.10110053
2008  -2.20031608 -0.70351162  2.49758506
2098   1.26829763  4.21564506  2.19574918
2284   3.84120978  0.85822441  2.60565027
2343   0.27039555  3.52239618  2.41042189
2390   3.54386041 -2.41283322  1.63353000
2426   1.26965866  3.98550923  3.22611949
2436  -1.46724991  1.57229826 -2.60757559
2451   2.54459730 -2.87594628  0.81783240
2580   0.20178539 -0.62120949 -1.87842022
2881  -1.02621692 -0.21177451  0.62260402
2928   3.54386041 -2.41283322  1.63353000
3219  -1.04461403  2.41585051 -1.23461445
3221  -2.80507879  1.01198774 -0.47112589
3366   1.10456790  4.14707165  2.45721784
3457   2.47699178  4.04064693  1.24494820
3492  -1.11313465  3.66877025  6.05190151
3911  -0.23638486  0.88944972  3.20480021
4322  -1.07191824  0.49491008  2.12763394
4347   1.31399894  3.50896047  0.69071926
4809  -2.51085330  1.58573398 -0.88787296
4848   0.34971406 -3.90048282 -1.36896997
5034   0.97094826  0.94458742  1.22362891
5143   1.66472364 -2.79393715  2.27606637
5511   0.36228861 -0.15896929 -1.65711237
6081   1.01987609 -0.15576396 -0.76417752
6512   1.50099391 -2.86251056  2.53753503
6814  -0.88088430  2.48442393 -1.49608311
7164  -0.85761906 -3.95562052  0.61220132
7182  -0.86248719 -0.14320110  0.36113536
7614   2.50025702 -2.39939751  3.35323263
7716   0.02061298 -0.61887701 -1.57987512
7748  -1.63097964  1.50372485 -2.34610692
7816   0.18598433 -3.96905623 -1.10750131
7908   0.03805566 -0.68978290 -1.61695155
8474  -2.17749677 -1.24974677 -3.28390098
8807   0.03805566 -0.68978290 -1.61695155
9533   3.33442937 -1.77472205  3.40002858
10256 -1.46724991  1.57229826 -2.60757559
10488 -1.20105297 -0.24039857  3.31328266
10906 -1.37797055  5.25133126  1.16141357
11444 -2.55065755 -0.68020900 -1.25593373
12051  2.38409409 -3.33818648  0.59652455
13041 -0.36688063  0.38427690  3.36007861
13143  0.85614636 -0.22433737 -0.50270885
13573  1.18037930  0.30647624 -0.54286967
13730  0.85614636 -0.22433737 -0.50270885
14327  0.19855888 -0.22754270 -1.39564370
14472  2.72899623 -3.27194554  0.03651079
14594 -0.97554028 -0.71927981  0.47933733
14746  0.64671531  0.41377381  1.26378973
15290  2.36976125 -2.90457034  3.50851104
15358  0.02061298 -0.61887701 -1.57987512
15380 -1.31721591 -1.17918753  0.55657458
15673  1.06022762  4.62362041  4.99261807
> length(unique(fit.data$objectscores[,4:6]))
[1] 288
```

[image: 3dplot]

Anyway, `jitter()` seems to work fine, thank you very much.
I just still don't understand why i can't see all 288 points. Are they too similar to be plotted differently? Can I increase the scale? i've also tried multiplying the data set by 10 and 100 but to no avail.

EDIT 4
Actually, recounting by hand the values in `unique(fit.data$objectscores[,4:6])` , they seem to be 95 record and not 288. I guess  `length(unique(fit.data$objectscores[,4:6]))` it's not the correct way to count them.

Comment: Please post some more information on your data.  You can't post all 15927 records, but you could include the first 20 using `dput(head(fit_data, 20))` (or maybe `dput(head(fit_data$objectscores, 20))`), and the result of running `str()` on your dataset.  My guess would be that you have a lot of repeated values:  the overplotting will hide most of them.

Comment: Did you use R to conduct PCA? If so, what package and function did you use? I'm not able to match the problem, so I'm wondering if it has to do with the structure. As far as the `plotly` example, you create used variable names, but those names do not exist in `new.tw`. (Or you did add the names, but didn't include the code here.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Please let me know if you need twitter.csv or anything else (the next part uses mclust to plot clusters via model based clustering, and it's the part where plot3d and plot_ly don't cause any problem)

Comment: Regarding counting values:  `unique(fit.data$objectscores[,4:6])` is a matrix, so `length()` counts all the entries in all three columns.  You can use `nrow(unique(fit.data$objectscores[,4:6]))` to find how many rows there are.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simply a case that there are a lot of repetitions in your data.  In your first 20 observations, there are 8 unique values, and you say that `unique(fit.data$objectscores[,1])` gave you 90 to 100 values.

You can run `unique(fit.data$objectscores[,4:6])` to see how many unique triplets there are, but I'd guess it's similar.  You say you see "less than 50" points plotted, which might be because it's hard to count points in a point cloud, or because some of them are very close together.

There are a number of tricks for displaying highly overlapping data in a plot.  The easiest to use is "jittering", using the `jitter()` function in R.  With the first 20 values, plotting using

```
plot3d(apply(scores[,4:6], 2, jitter, amount=0), 
       xlab = "Political", ylab = "Civil", zlab = "Partizan")
```

gives a reasonable result.  Experiment with different values for `amount` with your real dataset.